# symfony 4 prodection login fails on "login_check"

Tags: amazon-web-services, symfony, fosuserbundle

I am using symfony and fosuserbundle. my login fails at "login_check". I have tried re writting my security.yaml

```
security:
    access_denied_url: /login
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: bcrypt

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN
        ROLE_BROKER:      ROLE_BROKER

    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username

    firewalls:
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
                login_path: /login
                check_path: /login_check
                always_use_default_target_path: true
                default_target_path: /dashboard
                use_referer: true
            logout:       true
            anonymous:    true

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/apply, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/, role: ROLE_USER }
```

Here is my screen

[image]

Comment: Did you check `prod.log`?

Comment: Nothing in the prod.log